# tmux window exit when I exit prossess in tmux window

Tags: tmux

If I have a process like `rails c` or `guard` that I exit out of with the command exit the tmux window also exit.

This is not very practical when I just want to restart for example the rail console.

Can I prevent this behavior in tmux?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the `remain-on-exit` window option to prevent *tmux* from closing a window (pane) when the process running it ends.

```
setw remain-on-exit on
```

The session option `set-remain-on-exit` is also available; with it you can arrange for all the windows/panes of a session to automatically have `remain-on-exit` turned on.

---

After a `remain-on-exit` pane’s process ends, the pane will display the message “Pane is dead” until it is closed with the command `kill-pane` (or `kill-window`), or a new command is started there with `respawn-pane` (or `respawn-window`).

```
respawn-pane 'rails c'     # respawn with a specific command
respawn-pane               # respawn whatever the previous command
```

If you are not overly concerned about cleanly exiting a pane’s existing process, then you can even restart a pane without first exiting its current process like this:

```
respawn-pane -k            # kill current process (if any) and respawn the previous command
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this (`remain-on-exit`) on if the process exited with return code != 0?

Comment: @blueyed: None of the `remain-on-exit` code tests the exit status, but you could adjust it as the last step of your command. To have only non-zero exits remain you could start the window with something like `neww 'zsh -l || tmux set -q remain-on-exit' if `remain-on-exit` is normally off in your config (if it is normally on, then change to `&&`). This will only really work for single-pane windows though since having a split pane toggle the option for the whole window is probably not what you want.

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen thanks for your answer! Then it's probably not feasible to have this with [vim-dispatch](https://github.com/tpope/vim-dispatch), which is using a tmux pane to start a background process.